# NAS Server disconnecting from SMB connection

Tags: network, smb, nas

I can't figure it out:

Every few minutes I have to connect to the NAS Synology (DS1517+), DSM number (DSM 6.2.1-23824) from my MacBook: *Go>Connect to Server...* then select the folders I need.

Experiencing this from past few weeks, it never happened before. One possible reason to this can be: *We ordered a NAS Extension and after attaching it, our original NAS server failed to start. It was the hardware issue and had to order a replacement of the original box.*

Also, some forums says its Hibernating issue of the local volumes, but this isn't the case with me. I checked that NAS Status LED is off, which means it is not in Hibernation.

Meanwhile, I have done an indirect mapping to avoid re-connect using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/300087/os-x-how-to-avoid-having-to-re-connect-to-network-share-after-nas-was-turned-of/303011#303011) by @heesoo post.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance for your insight!

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). In the meantime, can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/351179/edit) your question to clarify how you know this isn't a hibernation issue and to let us know what else you've already tried to resolve this? Also, you say you've been experiencing this for the past few weeks - can you think of anything that coincided with this starting (e.g. any new hardware or software, etc)?

Comment: Thank you so much, I edited the post based on your suggestions, I hope that helps.